# How to save/write file over mapped network in PHP?

Tags: php, mapped-drive

I am **trying to save a file over a mapped network**, my PHP script is on server like `"111.123.5/file"`  here and I am trying to save file in mapped network like `"//123.222.333.01/getfile"` but it it not storing.

rather than storing on mapped network it stored in the same directory where PHP script is hosted.

P.s: I am saving an image on mapped network. also I have full access/permission in both directory.

```
  $filename_path = md5(time().uniqid()).".jpeg";

//  replacing data:image/jpeg;base64, from post request as It is not required for making Image
 $base64_string = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $base64_string);

 $base64_string = str_replace(' ', '+', $base64_string);
 $decoded = base64_decode($base64_string);

 //defining path
 file_put_contents("//123.222.333.01/getfile/".$filename_path,$decoded);
```

Comment: Are you running the script through CLI or through a web server (web page)?

Comment: running through webpage

Comment: How did you map the drive? Remember that the web server usually runs as a different user, which means that it won't have the same environment set up as you do when you log in to the machine. What OS are you running the web server on? What web server are you using? How is the drive mapped?

Comment: my drive in on windows and I am running PHP script on cantos on different server currently I am access my drive with an ip address which I enter in my run command in windows

Comment: What does _"I am access my drive with an ip address which I enter in my run command in windows"_ mean? How did you map the drive in CentOS? It's a bit unclear. Have you googled this issue? I know that there are plenty of questions/answers about reading/writing to mapped drives using PHP on linux. If you have, then please share what you've tried and what happened.